# Target all child images within list

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

I am trying to target all the image tags within the html code below:

```
<ul id = "test">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/example1.jpg">EXAMPLE TEXT 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/example2.jpg">EXAMPLE TEXT 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/example3.jpg">EXAMPLE TEXT 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

My CSS to target all the images within the test list:

```
#test li a > img{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

EDIT: #nav li a img{} also isn't effecting the image elements. If I give each img a class, then I can get the css to work properly, but I should be able to target without using a class on the images

How am I using the child selector incorrectly?

ANSWER: nevermind, the original CSS I have above does work. My code had an invisible character messing the everything up.

Comment: #test li a img{border:1px solid red} try this also it seems that you are not closing </li> hence your css may be not applying

Comment: @PravinVaichal I have also tried this, and again it has no effect on the image

Comment: You aren't closing your li tags correctly. I doubt this is affecting your CSS, though.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/6HU68/ please check markup here

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the markup typo. The issue is still with css targeting

Comment: In your edit you added "#nav" but in the code you provided the id is "#test", is it a typo? This could explain the error

Answer (score 2):

As you can see on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6Du5X/) fiddle it should work with this css:

```
ul#test>li>a>img{
   margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are not closing you tags properly Please find updated code

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6HU68/)**

**HTML**

```
<ul id="test">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/example1.jpg" />EXAMPLE TEXT 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/example2.jpg" />EXAMPLE TEXT 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img/example3.jpg" />EXAMPLE TEXT 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#test li a img {
    /*css code*/
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This tagets the images in the li
http://jsfiddle.net/UkmR3/1/

```
#test li a  img{
    margin-right:  100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#test {
  position:relative;
}
#test li{
  list-style: none;
  padding:5px 15px;
}
#test li img{
  float:left;
  margin-right:15px;
}
```